# GET and POST not working on AEM CQ6.2 Publish Instance

Tags: java, http-post, adobe, aem

I am working on adobe aem cq 6 and creating user with HttpPost from the java application. 
This code is **working fine** for **author instance** but it is **not working** on **publish instance**.

JAVA code

```
    public static void createUser() throws IOException
    {

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:4503/libs/granite/security/post/authorizables");
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("createUser", ""));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authorizableId", "dd90"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rep:password", "dd90"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile/email", "dd90@hotmail.com"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("intermediatePath", "/home/users/test/"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        try {
            System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity()));
            // do something useful with the response body
            // and ensure it is fully consumed
            EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
        } finally {
            response2.close();
        }
}
```

I get the error below from the cq error.log

> POST /libs/granite/security/post/authorizables HTTP/1.1]
>   com.adobe.granite.security.user.internal.servlets.AuthorizableServlet
>   Error while processing AuthorizableServlet POST
>   javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: null
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.util.NodeUtil.addChild(NodeUtil.java:113)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.util.NodeUtil.getOrAddTree(NodeUtil.java:171)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.user.UserProvider.createFolderNodes(UserProvider.java:306)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.user.UserProvider.createAuthorizableNode(UserProvider.java:257)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.user.UserProvider.createUser(UserProvider.java:185)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.user.UserManagerImpl.createUser(UserManagerImpl.java:162)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.UserManagerDelegator$9.perform(UserManagerDelegator.java:177)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.UserManagerDelegator$9.perform(UserManagerDelegator.java:173)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:208)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.UserManagerDelegator.createUser(UserManagerDelegator.java:173)
>           at com.adobe.granite.security.user.internal.servlets.AuthorizableServlet.create(AuthorizableServlet.java:800)
>           at com.adobe.granite.security.user.internal.servlets.AuthorizableServlet.doPost(AuthorizableServlet.java:707)
>           at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:149)
>           at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:345)
>           at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:376)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:546)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>           at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:151)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:362)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:177)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
>           at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:126)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:381)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:155)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
>           at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:114)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:220)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:181)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:292)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.analytics.provisioning.impl.UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:119)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:285)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
>           at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:67)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:169)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:84)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:216)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
>           at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>           at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>           at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>           at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>           at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:124)
>           at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:61)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have also tried using CURL command and it is working fine for both author and publish.

```
curl -u admin:admin -FcreateUser= -FauthorizableId=dd12 -Frep:password=testuser -Fprofile/email=dd@intel.com -Fprofile/age=32 -Fprofile/familyName=dd -Fprofile/givenName=dd -FintermediatePath="/home/users/test/" http://localhost:4503/libs/granite/security/post/authorizables
```

Unfortunately I cant use CURL for this project as there is environment limitation.

I am suspecting there are some configuration to enabled the GET and POST on publish instance since I can use the java code above for the author instance without fail. Can anyone please help me? I have spent 3days to find the solution and still struggling.

**Updated on 27/3/2017**

I found out just have to add and remove few lines of code , import java.util.Base64 and this issue solved.

Remove CredentialsProvider which setcredentials. Add the follow below httpPost declaration.

```
byte[] message = "admin:admin".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(message);
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization","Basic " + encodedString);
```

Comment: If your publisher has a runmode of publish then POST will be disabled so this is expected for 6.1+ versions. Normal practice is to create users on Author and replicate them. Is this not suitable for your case?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! yes, not suitable for my case. We have to create it on publish instance. Anyway to enable that?

Comment: Otherwise we have to automate the replication process from author to publish.. can automate replication be done in aem cq?

Comment: You can enable the POST in publisher but thats a bad security risk so I won't recommend it. Replication is easy to automate. I'll answer below as syntax is messed in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and recommended practice is to create users on Author and replicate them to publishers (unless you are using communities which is not in the scope of this question).

You already know how to create users on the Author via curl:

```
curl -u admin:admin -FcreateUser= -FauthorizableId=testuser -Frep:password=testuser -FintermediatePath="/home/users/test/" http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/security/post/authorizables
```

Once a user is created you can replicate it using the following curl command:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -F path="/home/users/test/testUser -F cmd="activate" http://localhost:4502/bin/replicate.json
```

That's the easier solution rather than opening up security holes in publisher.

For Java solution you can POST the replication command using the same Java code you have above with different path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks bro! it is working.  Let me add on the java code for the replication in this comment for those who having same issue.   List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
  nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", "/home/users/test/Oa86yFZPXNWArzKvEth3"));
  nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", "activate"));

Comment: How to enable GET/POST to the publish instance anyway?

Comment: Start a separate thread for specifically enabling POST on publisher for broader answer. Not something to fit in comments as it's too broad. You can link back to this question with a use case.

Comment: i have updated my post which include my latest solution. Thanks.